# How to fix windows.open() error in script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open several webpages listed in a file by a script. 
How should I open these links?

I tried to make it by `while()`. It works for href but not for `window.open()` unless there is no link in the expression.

```
<?php
// Datei öffnen zum lesen und schreiben open and read
$handle = fopen (".../urls.txt", "r");

while ( $inhalt = fgets ($handle, 4096 ))
    {
        echo "<li> $inhalt "; ?>
        <script> window.open("<?php echo $inhalt; ?>","_blank") </script>
        <a href="<?php echo $inhalt; ?>" target="_blank">TitleM</a>
        <?php
    }

fclose($handle);
?>
```

I want to open e.g. 7 different links in 7 new windows listed in url.txt.
By `href` they are all listed with `while()`.
However `window.open()` only opens the 7th link in a new window. 
The previous 6 links are ignored.
But if `window.open()` is without `$inhalt`, it opens seven new windows.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I tried, but only the last link is opened in a new window. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line-breaks are included in the return value of [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).
Therefore you should [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) $inhalt.

```
<script>
window.open("<?= trim($inhalt) ?>", "<?= md5($inhalt) ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second argument to `window.open()`. The second argument is the window name. If you set the same name on each iteration, it will keep targeting the same window.

Give the windows different names instead:

```
<script> window.open("<?= $inhalt; ?>", "<?= md5($inhalt) ?>") </script>
```

This will give the windows unique names, using the md5 hash of the URL.

You can read more about `window.open()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

**Side notes:**

You should check that the browser isn't blocking the popups.
It's also good practice to close your `<li>`-tags (even though it's optional).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still only window 7 opens (not 1-6).

Comment: I also tried:`$i++; `<script> window.open("<?php echo $inhalt; ?>", "<?php echo $i; ?>") </script>` So I get different windows-names. But there is no effect.

Comment: `<script> window.open("<?= $inhalt; ?>", "<?= md5($inhalt)?>") </script>` does not work while `<script> window.open("", "<?= md5($inhalt)?>") </script>` works (but with empty pages).

Comment: Ok, I'll see. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Also tried this: `<script> window.open("<?=$inhalt?>", "<?= md5($inhalt)?>") </script>`. Only window 7 is opened. With empty argument seven empty windows are opened (firefox, ie and edge)?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a solution:

```
<script> window.open(<?php echo "$inhalt";?>, "<?= md5($inhalt)?>") </script>
```

And the links in the txt-file have to be inbetween "". 
Sample: 
"domain1.tld"
"domain2.tld"
...
"domain7.tld"

Now it works. Each link is opened in a seperate window.

Comment: Isn't that what both (other) answers before this included? The only slight difference I see here, are quotes.

Comment: Because of this quotes the links did not get open. With `<script> window.open("<?= $inhalt; ?>", "<?= md5($inhalt) ?>") </script>` always only the last link from the file was opened in a window.